# A way to horizontally flip the entire screen in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for something similar to the question below, but written in .NET so the application can be re-used on any Windows 7 machine regardless of video drivers.

https://superuser.com/questions/554589/how-can-i-horizontally-flip-invert-my-monitor-not-rotate

To emphasize, flip is what I am looking for, not rotate. So, as if the entire screen is mirrored.

**Edit:** The solution I am after would flip the entire screen for all applications, at the OS level so-to-speak, rather than just flip the Window of my application.

Comment: in WPF that would be 1 line of XAML, but since you did not specify any UI technology, I assume you're using winforms, which does not support anything like this.

Comment: When you say any machine, you mean any Windows based PC, right (or possibly Linux with Mono)? I would say it would help if you edited your question to reflect your exact needs instead of linking to a question which might have details that change the solution. For instance, would just showing a fullscreen flipped screenshot be enough?

Comment: Thanks to both! I updated the question to specify Windows 7. As for the UI technology, this would be a new application built from scratch specifically to do this, so I guess we have the freedom to choose anything that is applicable.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with WPF, I assume what HighCore is taking about is application-related, not whole-screen related (HighCore please correct me if my assumption is wrong, Hanood please correct me if this is good enough for you, although the phrasing of the question makes me think it's not). Also, my first thought is still to show a fullscreen screenshot, only flipped. However, this would be a tad slow and would need some work if user interaction is needed so again, if you could write your intentions.

Comment: This calls for the lo-tech five dollar solution.  Use a mirror.

Comment: @hanood It's still unclear to me if you want to create an application that looks flipped, or an application that flips the Windows UI (desktop).

Comment: Haha @HansPassant, you're actually on the right track. The purpose of this is to be able to project information onto a giant mirror, and have the information readable on the mirror :)

Comment: Thanks again to everyone, I edited my question to clarify the intent, which is to flip all applications, not just mine.

Comment: [Horizontal mirror function?](http://www.p4c.philips.com/files/l/lc4100_40/lc4100_40_pss_aen.pdf)